# How to show NavigationBar on Android Things?

Tags: android-things

I tried add `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` in `/system/build.prop`, but is read-only system. 
Then I tried `mount -o remount`, `rw /system`, got

> mount: system' not in /proc/mounts

when I trying `mount -o remount, rw /`, got

> /dev/root' is read-only

How can I solve it ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation keys are not available on Android Things at all.

Comment: I'd justa add that it is a design decision because Android Things is mean to have a single app running (so home and multitask do not make sense) and most frequently it would be single screen, so back doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Hello, how to get root on Android Things?